# String is off by 1 character - C

Tags: c, string

I am writing a code for a weather database, but when I go to print out the city and temperatures my first line is off by 1 character, and I cannot figure out why. One thing I did notice was that when i print for example printf("%20s", city); only the first city is being modified.

This is for a intro to C-Programming and they have not learned much about strings yet, which is why I read in character by character.

Here is the snippet of code I am referring to;

```
while(TRUE) {
  for(
    i=0; 
    fscanf(input,"%c", &c)!=EOF && c!='#';
    i++)
  {  //i.e. city#..
    city[i]=c;
  }

  if(c=='#') {
    city[i] = '\0';         //Next line scans in the weather for the days of the week
    fscanf(input, " (%f, %f), (%d, %d), (%d, %d), (%d, %d), (%d, %d), (%d, %d), (%d, %d), (%d, %d)",&h_avg, &l_avg,&s1,&s2,&m1,&m2,&t1,&t2,&w1,&w2,&th1,&th2,&f1,&f2,&sa1,&sa2);
    printf("%20s  %d %d", city, s1,s2);
  } else {
    printf("\n"); 
    break;
  }  //Break infinite loop because for loop broke from EOF
}
```

Sample output:

```
           Baltimore 75 60
Miami  20 10
Washington D.C.  75 50
New York  75 50
```

only Baltimore is being right aligned. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `"%c"` scanf pattern does not skip whitespace, so you're likely getting whitespace in your city strings.  In particular, as you never scan past the newline (`\n`) at the end of the previous line, your city names would all start with newlines (except for the first one).  In addition, your `printf` never prints any newlines (other than the ones in the cities), so that explains what you are seeing.

More precisely -- your second city gets read as `"\nMiami"` (6 characters), so when its printed out with `"%20s"`, it prints 14 spaces first.  Those spaces are all printed on the end of the `Baltimore` line (as there is no newline printed at the end of it), and then it prints `"\nMiami"`

Try using:

```
for (i = 0; fscanf(input,"%c", &c)!=EOF && c!='#';) {
    if (i == 0 && isspace(c)) continue;
    city[i++] = c; }
while (i>0 && isspace(city[i-1])) i--;
```

to strip leading and trailing whitespace from the city name.